# Adiciona Mais um campo a Calculadora em Linha

Tags: javascript

Ola A Todos não sei muito de javascript e preciso de uma ajudinha. Nesse script no link a baixo no jsfiddle preciso adcionar mais um campo para realizar o calculo.
Ele paga o valor de um input  e multiplica por um outro input sendo que preciso adcionar um dropdown para realiar uma divisão. então ficaria assim

```
  Hoje é assim
        <input type="text" name="qtd" /> x
        <input type="text" name="valor" value="10" /> =
        <input type="text" name="total" value="resultado" />

   Gostaria assim
      qtd    <input type="text" name="qtd" /> x
      valor  <input type="text" name="valor" value="10" /> / 
             <select name="mark[]"   id="mark" > 
                <option value="0.80">0.80</option>
                <option value="0.85">0.85</option>
                <option value="0.90">0.90</option>
                </select>
        =    <input type="text" name="total" value="resultado" />

  Então
 QTD x VALOR = resultado / dropdown  =  input "total"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mxjfLu1x/

Comment: seu script está somando e não multiplicando, está correto?

Comment: correto...  mais ele e para multiplicar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta utilizar o código

```
var selectMark = parseFloat(document.getElementById("mark").value);
```

para pegar o valor do novo select, e então usá-lo para a realizar a divisão.

o link do código exemplo que você passou, está [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/mxjfLu1x/5/) atualizado

Atualização para funcionar como array

```js
function getClosest(el, tagName) {
  while (el = el.parentNode) {
    if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() == tagName) return el;
  }
}

//como nao estamos usando jquery, devemos realizar o loop para cada item selecionado

var classQtd = document.getElementsByClassName("qtd");
for (var i = 0; i < classQtd.length; i++) {
  classQtd[i].addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    updateValue(e);
  });
}

var classValor = document.getElementsByClassName("valor");
for (var i = 0; i < classValor.length; i++) {
  classValor[i].addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    updateValue(e);
  });
}

var classMark = document.getElementsByClassName("mark");
for (var i = 0; i < classMark.length; i++) {
  classMark[i].addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    updateValue(e);
  });
}

//funcao para atualizar os valores
function updateValue(e) {
  var total = 0;
  var qtd = 0;
  var valor = 0;
  var mark = 0;

  // ir buscar o outro valor dentro da mesma linha
  var tr = getClosest(e.target, 'tr');
  valor = tr.querySelector('input[name="valor[]"]').value;
  qtd = tr.querySelector('input[name="qtd[]"]').value;
  mark = parseFloat(tr.querySelector('select[name="mark[]"]').value);

  total = (qtd * valor) / mark;
  tr.querySelector('input[name="total[]"]').value = total;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="selectable">
    <td class="center">
      <input type="text" class="qtd" name="qtd[]" />
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <input type="text" class="valor" name="valor[]" value="10" />
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <select name="mark[]" class="mark">
        <option value="0.80">0.80</option>
        <option value="0.85">0.85</option>
        <option value="0.90">0.90</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <input type="text" class="total" name="total[]" value="resultado" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="selectable">
    <td class="center">
      <input type="text" class="qtd" name="qtd[]" />
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <input type="text" class="valor" name="valor[]" value="10" />
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <select name="mark[]" class="mark">
        <option value="0.80">0.80</option>
        <option value="0.85">0.85</option>
        <option value="0.90">0.90</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <input type="text" class="total" name="total[]" value="resultado" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="selectable">
    <td class="center">
      <input type="text" class="qtd" name="qtd[]" />
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <input type="text" class="valor" name="valor[]" value="10" />
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <select name="mark[]" class="mark">
        <option value="0.80">0.80</option>
        <option value="0.85">0.85</option>
        <option value="0.90">0.90</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <input type="text" class="total" name="total[]" value="resultado" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Perfeito isso mesmo, mais so uma coisinha!!! quando coloco a qtd ele inicia o calculo não é?  queria que quando altera-se a mark também refaça o calculo

Comment: @FabioHenrique, você pode incluir o evento no campo mark `document.getElementById("mark").addEventListener("change", function(e){
 alert(this.value);
});`, ae é só ajustar tudo, aconselho criar uma função de atualização, que será chamada pelos dois eventos.

Comment: Ola amigo não entendi como fazer..

Comment: @FabioHenrique para fazer isso que vc disse é sugiro olhar este [exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/mxjfLu1x/7/), onde alterei o código original e fiz com que a mudança nos dois campos altere o resultado. Alterei tb o `HTML` para incluir `ids` nas `tags`, facilita para o tratamento dos itens.

Comment: Ola Amigo o script antigo funcionava com array esse ja não funiona. segue o exemplo http://jsfiddle.net/mxjfLu1x/8/  oque pode ser

Comment: Ola Amigo uma das funcionalidades desse script é que ele funcionava em array como demonstrado aqui  jsfiddle.net/mxjfLu1x/8.  nesse modo não funciona. oque fazer nesse caso?

Comment: Olá @FabioHenrique, aqui tem um exemplo funcionando em um array, acredito que seja melhor migrar para `jQuery`, ficaria mais tranquilo o código. [Exemplo aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/mxjfLu1x/10/)